# What is this blue stuff on the threads of the p-trap under my bathroom sink?

Tags: plumbing, sink, pvc

I had one heck of a time getting the p-trap off while replacing the drain. I'm trying to figure out if this blue stuff is some type of thread sealant but I can't find anything on google that matches what I'm looking at. It is quite crusty, like dried toothpaste. I *think* that it made my job harder while trying to unscrew these things, but it is also possible that I'm just weak. I'll clean it off before putting everything back together, but I'm wondering if this is some product that I should be using. I was under the impression that one shouldn't be using any kind of cement on a p-trap.

[image]

Comment: It might just be me, but that bottom joint looks tilted.  Maybe just way it was(before putting on straight) when the picture was taken.  Tilted/crooked joints don't usually seal well.

Comment: it is typical plumbing thread sealant, not a cement, looks very much like hercules megaloc like was mentioned.  That stuff does not dry hard.  It is very easy to wipe and clean up with a wet paper towel.  **It did not make it harder to unscrew things.**  It's not likely to be beneficial using it on those trap threads in terms of leak prevention - that's not where the leak will happen.  But using megaloc, as cheap as it is and easy to use as it is, on something like that isn't a bad idea to keep any kind of threads from sticking or galling plastic or metal.

Comment: other possibility it could be Blue Monster thread sealant, which is that color blue, but is much thicker than Megaloc.  If I have real metal threads that require thread sealant I rarely use Megaloc because it's thin and watery the heavier stuff like Blue Monster that can be either blue or white is better, and they will dry to a harder flakier consistency.

Comment: When the questioner states **that it was difficult to unscrew, and it's hard and crusty,** telling them *that isn't the case* (which you, somehow, can tell from only a picture, and ignoring what the person actually there actually experienced) makes you the gaslighter.

Comment: retaliating because I negative one'd your thread lock answer, claiming that I gaslighted because I said *it did not make it harder to unscrew*, because it is in fact was a non hardening sealant, and of all things you yourself said *some **misguided idiot** used threadlocker such as loctite*...  really made me laugh.  I'm interested to know how I see a -1 in my trphy thing when all i did was a comment.

Comment: not to mention trap piping like that... especially when all misaligned... is never hard to unscrew when there's nothing on the plastic threads.  so obviously the hard to unscrew'ness was caused by the soft non hardening megaloc sealant.  And let's not forget it is also possible, he (she/it/they?) said it himself that *possible i'm just weak* so we should really also explore that aspect... i am so beside myself right now that I claimed that the megaloc simply was not the cause of the hard to unscrew'ness and didn't come out and say yeah you're just weak call a plumber.

Comment: and that 3 people had upvoted your misguided idiot used threadlock answer is all that really needs to be said here

Comment: You get a -1 for downvoting. Tale the [tour] if you find that a mystery.

Comment: @crip659 I think the way the photo was taken slightly exaggerates the tilt. The straight section is in fact slightly tilted but in real life it doesn't look like such an extreme angle. At the time I took this photo, both of the joints where unscrewed so the p-trap is just sitting in there with a mild bit of friction, so it may also be slightly askew from that.

Comment: @ron thank you for the extra bit of info about megaloc. It was in fact pretty easy to clean off with just a wet cloth. It was very dry and crumbly and didn't seem to adhere to the PVC. I really had to get my whole torso into the cabinet to get enough leverage on the rear-most joint to unscrew it. It took several attempts and I was not expecting it to be that difficult which is why I thought the product might have contributed to the difficulty. Given that it cleaned off so easily, I can believe that it was not this product making it difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Some misguided idiot put threadlocker such as Loctite (or a similar product, but blue is standard-strength Loctite brand) on there, it would appear.

Comment: I'm not going to DV but I think it's megaloc, which is that color and is perfectly acceptable to use in that way. Personally I would have used a softer product like rectorseal on those threads but I definitely don't think it's loctite.

Comment: I was thinking Megaloc thread sealant compound also -- however Ecernwal is correct, thread sealant is unnecessary on the upper two joints at least. They're both gasket-seal joints. I think the lower joint is a flare type, so thread sealant doesn't belong there either. It shouldn't hurt on any of them; just unnecessary.

Comment: @GregHill well, it greatly hurts ability to clean the trap. Trap is meant to be easily dis- and re-assembled. Locking the thread defeats the purpose.

Comment: it's not `threadlock`.

Answer (score 2):

Hercules Megaloc thread sealant compound

or RectorSeal Tru-Blu

Sometimes used for added on leak prevention on pipes exposed to vibration.

Drain paipe has no pressure and it is not exposed to vibration, so using tread sealants is not required.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. For posterity, at the time of this writing links to both products are at https://www.oatey.com/products/hercules-megaloc--1330684393 and https://rectorseal.com/rectorseal-tru-blu-group/

Comment: @cheshirekow nice....