# What is this blue stuff on my oil tank bung?

Tags: oil

I'm trying to install a smart oil monitor on my oil tank, which requires me to remove one of the bungs.  [image: Close-up picture of oil tank]  Instead of pipe dope, which is what I was expecting, each bung is sealed by some sort of hard blue material holding it in place.  What is it, and how do I remove it so I can unscrew the bung?

Comment: Tru Blu thread sealant? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/267362/what-is-this-blue-stuff-on-the-threads-of-the-p-trap-under-my-bathroom-sink

Comment: Twisting the plug counterclockwise should loosen it.  It's a sealer, not a glue.

Comment: Turning the plug counterclockwise doesn't loosen it; I tried that for a while, with the biggest pipe wrench I have.